# Create instances of a main array for multiple objects that updates from the main array

Tags: arrays, swift, realm

This is sort of an odd question that I hope I'm describing accurately enough for people to understand, but:

I have RealmModelObjects (called `People`), and I have a global array called `selectedListItems`. The array `selectedListItems` contains `RealmListItem`s, so each item in the array has multiple properties. One particular property of these that I care about is `listItemStatus`.

Ideally I'd like to generate an instance of `selectedListItems` for each `Person` in `People`, such that I'd be able to modify only that individual `Person`'s `listItemStatus` of the `indexPath.row`. However, I'd also like these instances to update themselves if the global array `selectedListItems` has stuff added or removed, *without* resetting any `listItemStatus`es that have already been changed.

This is my global array:

```
var selectedListItems = [
    RealmListItem(value: ["A", "Dog", 4, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["A", "Squirrel", 3, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["B", "A+", 3, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["B", "B-", 2, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["M", "Art", 5, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["M", "Sculpture", 1, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["P", "Hitler", 2, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["P", "Mao Zedong", 5, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["R", "Aunt", 3, 1, true]),
        RealmListItem(value: ["R", "Nephew", 1, 1, true])
]
```

Built off of this RealmModelObject:

```
class RealmListItem: Object {

    dynamic var category = ""
    dynamic var listItem = ""
    dynamic var listItemWeight = Double()
    dynamic var listItemStatus = Double()
    dynamic var isSelected = Bool()
}
```

I'd like to have an instance of `selectedListItems` generated for each `Person` so I can change the `listItemStatus` of the same RealmListItem between two people.

For example, I'd like to be able to change Steve's listItemStatus at "Dog" to 2, while Jessica's listItemStatus at "Dog" should be 0.

Is that possible, and if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Could you please provide some of your related code because it's not clear what you're going to do from your question.

Comment: @Dmitry sure thing, apologies for not being clear. I've edited my post to show some of the code and hopefully elaborate enough that my goal is understandable!

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not completely clear for me :( But I think that if you want every `Person` to have it's own `RealmListItem` you should use relationships for that, please check out the docs at: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships